# UPDATE при параллельных запросах

Tags: mysql, sql, транзакции

Существует таблица со следующими столбцами:
index int (primary key) | userid varchar | userindex int NULL

Задача: необходимо у **случайной** строки, которая имеет значение NULL в столбце userindex, заменить userindex на указанное значение.

Решение было следующим:

```
UPDATE table SET `userindex` = 1 WHERE `userindex` IS NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Внимание, вопрос: Безопасно ли использование данного запроса при возможных одновременных запросах? Не получится ли изменение одной и той же строки в разных запросах?
Поможет ли использование транзакции?

Comment: Какова цель мероприятия? Похоже на резервирование записи для дальнейшей обработки... если так, то надо в поле вместо NULL записывать не абстрактную единицу, а идентификатор текущего процесса, уникальный в рамках инстанса сервера. Т.е. UPDATE (попытка резервировать), потом SELECT (проверка, не перехватил ли кто), и если запись вернулась - обрабатывать, а если не вернулась (перехватили) - делать новую попытку резервирования. Но, поскольку источник данных однотабличный, подзапросы отсутствуют, изменяемая запись блокируется, а любой запрос сам себе транзакция, то и так будет работать без коллизий.

Comment: Да, задача стоит именно зарезервировать для сущности user заранее сгенерированный особым способом уникальный userid из этой таблички. Спасибо за ответ.